# Generalize Ruby RSPEC Expect

Tags: ruby, rspec

For RSPEC expectations I am trying to write some common functions

AssertionValue, property_Got , needed_Operator - All are Strings

```
  (expect(property_Got).to include AssertionValue; return) if needed_Operator.include? 'contains'
  (expect(property_Got).to eql AssertionValue; return)     if needed_Operator.include? 'equals'
  (expect(property_Got).to > AssertionValue; return)       if needed_Operator.include? 'gt'
```

etc ..  I need to generalize the Operator and code a single line - can someone help like

```
expect(property_Got).to *Generalize - Send method or args ?* array_Assert[3];
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to do this yet... and judging by the number of downvotes - neither does anyone else. If you can explain why this is the only way to do this thing, then we can begin to help - or we can offer alternatives that will complete the same requirements but in a more Best Practice kind of way. For instance: have you considered shared_examples ? From the very little information you have given, it could solve your problem.. or it could not - you haven't given enough information for us to know if it would.

Comment: Are you asking how to write custom marchers? http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs

Comment: Nop - this is what I am trying to do.
[1]. Get some references for elements
[2]. Find them 
[3]. Get their properties
[4]. Verify the properties match 'xxxx' something.. 
[5]. I dont want to split too many functions that people need to constantly go forward and back ward trying to understand. - so instead of calling a function and say write 50 or 100 expectations - I am trying to concisely write a single line.

Comment: Also from your comments - should i be reading between the lines that the technical details are vague ?. If not why do really people need to know what I am trying to do, the query seems to be simple one at that - condense >10 or > 20 lines of code into a single one.

Answer (score 2):

Part of what makes Rspec such a beautiful testing framework is how it encourages you to write tests so that **other developers can read and understand the intent of the code**.

There is a tradeoff in trying to refactor your tests so much that they are no longer clear what you're actually testing. This code, even if it were complete, would fall into that category

```
(expect(property_Got).to ***GeneralizeOperator*** array_Assert[3]; return) if needed_Operator.include? ***ArraySomethingGeneral*?**
```

consider the traditional approach

```
expect("string").to include "s"
expect("string").to eq "string"
expect("string").to be > "str"
```

Comment: Miles - Though I appreciate you spending time to answer, I am not asking for your advice. I am here to get a technical answer, if you cannot answer it appreciate just putting comments or leaving it blank.  
the expectation comes around a wrapper to reduce number of lines and not to do assertions by itself. if you did not read the question fully let me help you to understand. this is part of  a common module to combine 3 or 4 repeated actions - one of which is various tyopes of possible assertions. hence i am trying to get those values and support as many assertions possible.

Comment: @KiulLogoto - because you did not explain *why* you needed this, you are certainly going to get answers that explain that it is not generally considered good practice. Please understand that the above is a perfectly reasonable answer for your question as stated... it is very common on Stack Overflow for people to ask a question and just not realise that there is a better (and more accepted) way of doing things... so answering with how people normally do it is a very good answer.

Comment: @Taryn - The question is perfectly clear isnt it ? i dont understand why people cant read and interpret things correctly. I did not ask for opinion did I ? I only asked for a way if generalizing of sending methods/ operators if possible, Pt 2 - i dont think anyone at all needs to know why is it needed. its irrelevant nor provides any additional technical details. I did not come around asking for design considerations either. As far as I see my original question. Its a simple question and i am just advising people not to be too over assuming or over simplifying because they are experts.

Comment: And secondly it irritates me that some one has upvoted this guy's answer when all he did was copy paste and modify something that I am already doing it .And on top of that instead of answering a question he started talking about theories.

Comment: @KiulLogoto -" i dont think anyone at all needs to know why is it needed" - unfortunately this turns out not to be the case... even just in the people that I have helped, lots of people have benefited when they explained why they needed it... and I was able to give them a more in-depth answer that solved their problem the Rails Way. You don't think you need this kind of help - but unless you tell us (so that we can be sure).. you could be wrong. The only way to be sure you are not wrong is to actually tell us, so we can see why.

Comment: Pt 2 - it really irritates us that we are trying to help you, and that we clearly have heaps of experience in helping other people, but you seem to be throwing that experience away as though it's not valuable to you, and basically insulting all the people trying to help. Do you want to be ignored? or could you just suspend your disbelief long enough to humour us and give us the information that we are asking for? Who knows? maybe we'll find out that it really is not relevant... or maybe we will.

Comment: But until and unless you're wiling to "come to the party"... then people are not going to be wiling to help... you are asking us for a favour after all, the least you can do is give us what we ask for in return (ie more information).